# Recursion in Prolog Query

Tags: prolog

I have a database like this:

```
traject(departure,arrive,transport).

traject(London,Paris,train).
traject(Paris,Madrid,train).
traject(Madrid,Lisbon,bus).
traject(Madrid,Berlin,plane).
traject(Berlin,Prague,bus).
```

I have the rule:

```
connection(Departure,Arrrive):-traject(Departure,Arrive,Transport).
connection(Departure,Arrrive):-traject(Departure,X,Transport),traject(X,Arrive).
```

With that rule I can know if I ask the query connection(Paris,Lisbon) for example that the answer will be YES.

How can I made a rule and/or a query where I can answer this questions:

A) `transport(Paris,Lisbon)`

and the answer should come: train and bus

B) `traject_between(Paris,Lisbon)`

and the answer should come: Madrid

Comment: Prolog atoms need to start in a lower-case letter. `traject(London,Paris,train).` is the same as `traject(_,_,train).`

Comment: You should attempt solving this problem independently, it's not too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have atom's name starting with upper case letter, use single quotes: `traject( 'London', 'Paris', train)`.

I prefer to use short, suggestive variable names in the code, making it easier to track mentally and visually (YMMV of course):

```
connect(D,A):- traject(D,A,T).
```

Later you say you want to see the transport, so why are you ignoring it here? Change this to

```
connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,A,T).
connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,X,T1), traject(X,A,T2).
```

you have two transports now, in the second case. Combine them together somehow! A hint: what type of data can hold both two and one entry in it? You will have to change the first clause, too, to be consistent.

Now the new problem is, you ignore the waypoint, `X`. Another, related one is that you only make two legs in your journey, but what if you need three, or more?

Recursion will help solve both of these problems:

```
connect(D,A, Xs,Ts):- traject(D,A,T), Xs = ... , Ts = ... .
connect(D,A, Xs,Ts):- traject(D,X,T), 
                      connect(X,A, Xs2,Ts2),  % <---- recursion!
                      Xs = ... ,
                      Ts = ... .
```

Instead of `...`, something sensible must appear.  `connect(D,A, Xs,Ts)` means, `D`eparture and `A`rrival are connected by a *list* of waypoints `Xs`, using transport types `Ts`. So if `D` and `A` are directly connected by just one `traject(D,A,Transport)` arc, what is the list of waypoints? What is the list of transport types? --- Otherwise, if we can go from `D` to  `X` in one step using a type of transport `T`, and `X` and `A` are connected with a list of waypoints `Xs2` using transport types `Ts2`, what is the complete list of waypoints? What is the complete list of transport types?

When you finish this,  you will be able to define the two predicates that you ask for, quite easily, because the information is already there, in this `connect/4` predicate (`.../4` means, it has 4 arguments).

Comment: thank you Will Ness for your answer. I've tried to use the rules you propose, but I'm quite new in Prolog, what do you mean by completing the missing code on the dots? I though it was not needed to use that conjunctions...

And what query would I ask for example to know what are the transports I need between 2 or more cities ?

Thank you again in advance..I'm a rookie in Prolog and need to understand it...